# Multiple <atom:link> elements in RSS feed

Tags: rss, atom-feed

I am working on a Drupal module proving RSS feed generation (though not posting it to Drupal Answers, as my question is not really Drupal-related).

What I am wondering is whether an RSS feed could have multiple `<atom:link>` elements? (Or any other element for that matter?)

For example, [PubSubHubbub](http://code.google.com/p/pubsubhubbub/wiki/RssFeeds) requires an `<atom:link>` with `rel` attributes set to `hub` and `href` pointing to feed's update hub.

On the other hand, the same `<atom:link>` [could be used](http://feed2.w3.org/docs/warning/MissingAtomSelfLink.html) with `rel` attribute set to `self` and `href` pointing to feed's URL.

Which means, if I want to use both, I would need to include `<atom:link>` element twice in my feed. Or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can have multiple `<atom:link>` elements, each one would have a different `rel` attribute. That is valid Atom XML and customary practice.

You should review the [Atom spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4287) and the [RSS spec](http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/rss/rss.html), too.

Comment: Ok, thanks. RSS spec I already know pretty well, it does not say anything about multiple elements of the same type. Happy now then that I have assumed it should be possible and accounted for this in my module.